# Object being populated shows null fields in log (IOS, OBJ-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm populating an object's fields from Labels, when displaying in Log the label is the correct value, but the object's field is null. I'm coming over from an Android/ Java background and this is just awkward.
Any help would be great.

To be clear, the "soil type field" log shows "example"while the "soil type" log shows (null)

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

    Soil *thisSoil = self.thisSoil;

    thisSoil.soilType = self.soilNameField.text;
    NSLog(@"soil  type field %@", self.soilNameField.text);
    NSLog(@"soil type: %@", thisSoil.soilType);

    thisSoil.frictionAngle = [self.frictionAngleValue.text integerValue];

    if ([self.soilUnitsSwitch isOn] ) {
        thisSoil.cohesion = [self.cohesionValue.text doubleValue];
        thisSoil.unitWeight = [self.unitWeightValue.text doubleValue];
    }else{
        thisSoil.cohesion = [self.cohesionValue.text doubleValue];
        thisSoil.unitWeight = [self.unitWeightValue.text doubleValue];
    }
    [self.delegate SoilCreatorViewController:self didFinishItem:thisSoil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The entire controller .m file

```
#import "SoilCreatorViewController.h"

#define IMPERIAL_TO_METRIC 0.3048
#define KG_TO_LBS 2.2

@interface SoilCreatorViewController ()

@end

@implementation SoilCreatorViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)soilQuestions:(id)sender {

        [self popupmaker :@"Friction Angle" : @"Phi is the angle of internal friction for soil, which governs soil strength and resistance. This value should be attained from competent field testing and the judgment of a licensed engineer."];

        [self popupmaker :@"Soil Cohesion": @"Cohesion defines the non-stress dependent shear strength of soil and should be used with caution. Typically,cohesion occurs in stiff, over-consolidated clays or cemented native soils. Cohesion should be neglected if the designer is unsure of its presence."];
}

- (IBAction)SwitchDidChange:(id)sender {
           if ([sender isOn]) {

            self.cohesionUnits.text = @"Ft";
            self.unitWeightUnits.text= @"M";


        }else{
            self.cohesionUnits.text = @"M";
            self.unitWeightUnits.text = @"M";

        }
    }

- (IBAction)unitWtDidChange:(id)sender {
    self.unitWeightValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", (double)self.unitWeightStepper.value];

}

- (IBAction)frictionAngleDidChange:(id)sender {
    self.frictionAngleValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)self.frictionAngleStepper.value];

}

- (IBAction)cohesionDidChange:(id)sender {
    self.cohesionValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", (double)self.cohesionStepper.value];

}

- (IBAction)textFieldDismiss:(id)sender {

    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}


- (IBAction)UnitSwitch:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isOn]) {
        self.unitWeightUnits.text = @"LBS/cubic Ft.";
        self.cohesionUnits.text = @"imp";
    }else{
        self.unitWeightUnits.text = @"KG/m3";
        self.cohesionUnits.text = @"met";
    }
}

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

    Soil *thisSoil = self.thisSoil;

    thisSoil.soilType = self.soilNameField.text;
    NSLog(@"soil  type field %@", self.soilNameField.text);
    NSLog(@"soil type: %@", thisSoil.soilType);

    thisSoil.frictionAngle = [self.frictionAngleValue.text integerValue];

    if ([self.soilUnitsSwitch isOn] ) {
        thisSoil.cohesion = [self.cohesionValue.text doubleValue];
        thisSoil.unitWeight = [self.unitWeightValue.text doubleValue];
    }else{
        thisSoil.cohesion = [self.cohesionValue.text doubleValue];
        thisSoil.unitWeight = [self.unitWeightValue.text doubleValue];
    }
    [self.delegate SoilCreatorViewController:self didFinishItem:thisSoil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)popupmaker:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)message{
    UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:title
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil
                          ];
    [alert show];
}
@end
```

The .h file

```
#import "Soil.h"

@class SoilCreatorViewController;

@protocol SoilCreatorViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)SoilCreatorViewController:(SoilCreatorViewController *)controller didFinishItem:(Soil *)item;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SoilCreatorViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CalculationDetailViewController.h"





@interface SoilCreatorViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<SoilCreatorViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *soilNameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *soilUnitsSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Soil  *thisSoil;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *frictionAngleStepper;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *unitWeightStepper;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *cohesionStepper;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *unitWeightValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *frictionAngleValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cohesionValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *unitWeightUnits;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cohesionUnits;

- (IBAction)soilQuestions:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)SwitchDidChange:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)unitWtDidChange:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)frictionAngleDidChange:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cohesionDidChange:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldDismiss:(id)sender;


- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender;
-(void)popupmaker:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)message;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any code that sets up thisSoil. At some point in your code, you need to write something like

```
self.thisSoil = [[Soil alloc] init];
```

or self.thisSoil will stay nil forever.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth. Nothing more to say!